# ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST

Tags: wordpress

I am placing my url to page speed to check my page speed.I am getting an error

```
Lighthouse returned an error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 403)Dismiss
```

please help me

Comment: Have you an `.htaccess` file denying requests ?  Does the website response if you navigate with a "PrivateBrowser" ?

Comment: htaccess is ok if it has a problem so it will no work with ip